# Finding done within seconds if pattern matches in file... if pattern is not present takes an hour to exit the loop

Tags: perl

```
open(FH,"some.txt") or die("\nFile not found\n");
my $find;
while(<FH>)
{
     ($find) = $_ =~m/^(scaffold110132\s+6126\s+C\b\s+.+?)(?=\n|$)/;
     print "\n***$find***\n" if ($find);
     last if($find);

}
```

It's a small piece of code to find a pattern in a some.txt file. If the pattern is present Perl gives it out in a jiffy. Whereas if the pattern is not present code takes an hour to exit the loop. Can somebody help me reason out why?

some.txt:: size :: 45Gb
extract of content ::

```
scaffold110637  42  A   1   ^!. C
scaffold110637  43  A   1   .   C
scaffold110637  44  T   1   .   C
scaffold110637  45  A   1   .   F
scaffold110637  46  T   1   .   F
scaffold110637  47  T   1   .   F
scaffold110637  48  A   1   .   F
scaffold110637  49  C   1   .   F
scaffold110637  50  A   1   .   H
scaffold110637  51  C   1   .   H
```

Comment: can you share what your file looks l ike and how large it is? how many lines is it? when you get a pattern nmatch which line does it occur on? as soon as you match your loop exists so if match is early then you dont proces the rest of the file. If you dont match then you need to read and process the entire file.

Comment: pls. note that some.txt is of size 45gb... and im using a low end desktop with 4gb ram to access it

Comment: File is very big and its taking time to reading line by line. If it didn't pattern its keep reading.

Comment: is it really so?? coz it finds even the last line of the file in seconds.. i hav tried

Comment: how do you know that its the last line and that the pattern in the last line was not found else where in the file?

Comment: how can i exit the loop (which is taking hours) if the pattern is not present in the file

Comment: coz itz an mpileupfile.. which does not have repeats of lines@ Chris Doyle.. n i checked the txt by the tail command in linux and tried to find that through the code

Comment: If you used tail on the linux command line, also use grep to check if your pattern is not in the middle.

Comment: already did that@simbabque

Comment: try using `$.` to report what line the loop is on. `$.` is the current line within a `while` loop. not every line, as printing to screen will add time, but perhaps every 10,000 lines or so (depending on how many lines the file has): `print "line: $." if ($. / 10000) =~ /^\d+$/`. `/^\d+$/` matches a whole number.

Comment: Could you report how long it take to scan the file using `grep` command/program?

Comment: Also: What are you _actually_ trying to find? I have a suspicion that you're 'spending' some CPU time needlessly because of the nongreedy captures and line end anchoring. If you're just trying to match and catch line, you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

I very strongly suspect that when the loop goes a long time, there's a line in your file that begins with `scaffold110132` and then almost matches the regular expression, but not quite. I suspect that your script is getting stuck on this line. That is, I suspect it isn't an issue of "pattern not being in file" but one of "lines that don't match the regex but slow things up".

I must admit, I'm not sure what kind of line could do that - do your lines end in `\n` characters, or do they end in `\r\n`?

However, I would suggest two things:

First off, try this since it's likely faster when the line isn't found: (and finds the same lines)

```
open(FH,"some.txt") or die("\nFile not found\n");
my $find;
while(<FH>)
{
     next unless /^scaffold110132/;
     ($find) = $_ =~ m/^(scaffold110132\s+6126\s+C\s.+)/;
     print "\n***$find***\n" if ($find);
     last if($find);
}
```

Though since some of us are still curious as to what was taking so long, could you also try this and tell us what the output was?

```
use Time::Hires qw( time );
use Data::Dumper;

open(FH,"some.txt") or die("\nFile not found\n");
my ($find, $start, $end);
my $maxtime = 0.0;
my $slowline = '';
while(<FH>)
{
     $start = time;
     ($find) = $_ =~m/^(scaffold110132\s+6126\s+C\b\s+.+?)(?=\n|$)/;
     print "\n***$find***\n" if ($find);
     $end = time;
     if ($end - $start > $maxtime) {
         $slowline = $_;
         $maxtime = $end - $start;
     }
     last if($find);
}
print Data::Dumper->Dump([$maxtime, $slowline], [qw($maxtime $slowline)]);
```

Comment: Why not just `chomp; if (/^scaffold110132\s+6126\s+C\s/) { print "\n***$_***\n"; last; }`?